# IEEE Style Using BibDesk and texshop

Tags: bibtex, texshop, bibdesk

I am trying to get the reference list compiled in TeXShop

I do not know what I'm doing wrong

I created a file in bibDesk and I put it in the same file that i have my .tex file in, and I even named them with the same name

I clicked: typeset bibtex first and then I did typset latex with no luck

in my document I am referring to a source by typing:

```
\cite{the name of the source inside my .bib file}
```

and at the end of the document I am doing:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{the name of the .bib file}
\end{bibliography}
```

The errors I get are:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file 
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file
```

I have the citation command written
and I have the bib file 
and I have the bib style command

please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I don't use TeXshop but have you compile your document with LaTeX before running bibTeX?

Comment: @RomainPicot thank you, I did not know I have to compile the latex file before the bibtex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how TeXshop work. But it seems that you have not compiled the document first.

To have the bibliography, you have to:

- Compile the document first % this will create tag to know which entry are cited or not
- Run bibtex % this will permits to match the key cited with the bibliography
- Compile the document **two** times % This will create the bibliography, insert the tag and the second compilation enables the software to know the new pages due to the bibliography add